# How to auto run a script every 30 min, store the output data on my server, and alert me about changes?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I created a PHP script that checks the value of a `price` field from some API system.

Now, I want my server to:

1. Run this script automatically, every 30 minutes (should it be with Cron Jobs?)
2. Store the data somewhere - Should it be in a database? I used the cPanel MYSQL wizard to create my first database, but have no idea how to continue from here.
3. Send me an email alert whenever the price changes, compared to the previous recorded price value.

Here is the script:

```
$myHeaders = array("key:  secretkey");

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$myHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$returnResult = curl_exec($ch);

// here the dom is generated
$xml = simplexml_load_string($returnResult);

echo $xml->products->product->price->__toString();

//not sure what the rest of this code does:

if ($returnResult) {
    //parse HTTP Body to determine result of request
    if (stripos($returnResult,"Error Code ")) {
        // error occurred
        trigger_error($returnResult,E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else{
        // success
        //echo $returnResult;
    }
}

else{
    // connection error
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch),E_USER_ERROR);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

How can I accomplish all this?

Comment: 1) Yes! 2) Yes or serialize/json_encode to a file. 3) **Compare** and mail if change! LOL

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you need to [make a cronjob](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs). (or at least the easiest way)
2. Yes storing the data in a database is the smartest and easiest to do.

[First read some tutorials on how to use MySQL database, look into MySQLi or PDO.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) 
Your Host is `localhost` and you choose the name of the database, username and password when you created your database.

3. This you can do with PHP itself, [it's pretty easy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

   `mail("someemail@domain.tld","Subject","Message ");`
   it returns a boolean value.

UPDATE 1:

PDO example:

```
try {
    //connect to database
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDatabase", "user", "secret");
    //Sets PDO to throw exceptions.
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //make SQL statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
            VALUES ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')";

    //Execute the SQL statement
    $conn->exec($sql);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDO error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Hope this gives you a basic understanding on how to use SQL PDO, else look at the link I send before, there are code examples for MySQLI and PDO in the tutorial.

Comment: to run a php code, i load php file. but where and how do i run a mysql code?

Comment: @rockyraw, did you look at the link I send? 
If you look through the link, there are multiple chapters on how to do it all, it's pretty straight forward. I will update my answer with a little example on how to connect with PDO then...